# Loop through several props objects in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2

I want to simply loop through several props object data in my component, so for example:

I have created a card component and passing as props objects:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="(title, index) in titles" :key="index" class="counter">
      <div class="title ">
        <span>{{ title }}</span>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <span>{{ values.value1 }}</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <Button :prop1="moreActions.prop1" :prop2="moreActions.prop2" 
              :prop3="moreActions.prop3" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="counter">
      <div class="title">
        <span>{{ titles.usersA }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <span>{{ values.values2 }}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
         <Button :prop1="moreActions.prop1" :prop2="moreActions.prop2" 
              :prop3="moreActions.prop3" />
      </div>
    </div> -->
    // more div here.....

 </div>
</template>


<script>
import Button from "../test/testButton";

export Test {
  name: "Card",
  components: {
    Button,
  },

**//Comment: I want to loop through each objects ( titles, values, moreActions)**

  props: {
    titles: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
    values: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
    moreActions: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
and in app.vue , i am passing the data something like this:

export const test = createTest ({
 .........
  props:   // I can say 'data' too
  {
    titles: {
      testA: "testA",
      usersA: "TestB",
      testc: "test3",
      textd: "Test4",
    },
    values: {
      value1: "9000",
      value2: "600",
      value3: "100",
      value4: "2",
      ofTotal: " of 9",
    },
    moreActions: {
      prop1: "Test",
      prop2: "testIcon",
      prop3: "test",
    },
  }

});
```

in the second div I can loop through like this and so on:

```
<div  v-for="(value, index) in values" :key="index" class="content">
        <span>{{ value }}</span>
 </div>
```

but then it doesnot look goods, I want to loop through every props objects in one v-for loop instead giving v-for loop to each div. how can I do that in efficient way.
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: There's no 1:1 correspondence between `titles` and `values`, with `values` having one extra key. How do we know which values in `titles` should be matched to which entry in `values`?